# error when refreshing children component Angular2

Tags: angular

Here is my module code. So my app goes like this: login  (press button to go to dashboard)-> dashboard (press link to go to children component)-> online/offline component.

They are all on the same page.

The way I use to navigate them:

```
this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']

routerLink= '/dashboard/online

routerLink= '/dashboard/offline
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        JsonpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
            path: 'login',
            component: LoginComponent

        },{
            path: 'dashboard',
            component: DashboardComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'online',
                    component: OnlineComponent
                },{
                    path: 'offline',
                    component: OfflineComponent
                },{
                    path: '',
                    redirectTo: 'online',
                    pathMatch: 'full'

                }
            ]
        },{
            path: '',
            redirectTo: '/login',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        }
        ])
    ],
```

**It works fine for routing. But if I refreshed the page when the url bar shows localhost:3000/dashboard/online. The page wont load after refreshing. The console shows such error:**

```
error at GET http://localhost:3000/dashboard/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js 
error at GET http://localhost:3000/dashboard/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js 
error at GET
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js 
error at GET http://localhost:3000/dashboard/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js 
Uncaught ReferenceError, system is not defined.
```

I think it has to do with the way I set the children component or I might need to add base href in Dashboard Component since it has children components.

Please help me with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might have to do with the angular router problem related to back/forward arrows and refreshing. I had a very similar problem.

I don't know for a fact if this will do it, but try this in your app.module, it switches the strategy for location back to the good old hashtag thing (so urls look like http://foo/#/bar instead of just http://foo/bar). Once I did this, all refreshing and forward/backward nav problems went away (for example, if I went from my site to www.amazon.com and then hit the back arrow, the server would respond with tons of "not founds" and so on):

```
// other imports
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  imports: [ ... ],
  providers: [ 
     {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy} 
   ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Hi @Tim Thank you for answering.  are provide and useClass reserved words?

Comment: I don't think they're reserved, just required keys on the provider objects. Don't quote me on that.